# return php code as return value from php extension

Tags: php, c++, c, swig, php-extension

I want to return the following php code :

```
(include "x.php");
```

as return value from my swig developed php extension. I have searched but found no specific answers. This return value will display as follows in the php script.

```
<?php
dl("myextension.dll");

my_extension_function(); /*this function call should output the following:
  (include "x.php"); in this php script*/

?>
```

Kindly help.

Regards,

KPM

Comment: What's in x.php? Do you want to catch the output?

Comment: Yes i want to display the output of x.php in the php script